# Laravel 8 API Unauthorized Handler Not Showing

Tags: json, laravel, api, postman

I would like to add a custom response when an endpoint is being accessed without access token. I added this line of code into my Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ],401);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Instead of getting the json response, I got a blank response with 500 error code on postman. What am I doing wrong?
The Response:
[image]

Comment: Be sure to be sending the right headers in your request `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: I tried adding the Content-Type: application/json in my request but the response is still blank. Is there any chance that is something wrong with the Handler.php itself?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by making sure that the server's response is in JSON. So I made a middleware file called ForceJsonResponse.php. Here is the code:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Registered it in Kernel.php on $middleware as

```
\App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
```

And in $routeMiddleware as

```
'json.response' => \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
```